# What is the standard for determining addiction?

Tags: united-states, florida, alcohol, drugs

The purchase of a firearm requires a statement that the purchaser is not addicted to controlled substances.  That being said, is there a "bright line" for determining alcohol addiction?   What exactly is the litmus test be for alcohol addiction?

Addiction may be obvious (loss of job, DUI, etc.) however, is one glass of wine with dinner every day  (consumption frequency) qualify as addiction?

Comment: Loss of job and DUI doesn't mean you are addicted. The only time you had alcohol in the last year was during the company's Christmas party, then you got drunk, punched your boss, and drove off going through all red traffic lights.

Comment: What is the actual wording of the question or statement that needs to be affirmed on the application form?

Answer (score 3):

[18 USC 922(d)(3)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/922) prohibits transfer to a person if you "know or have reasonable cause to believe" they unlawfully use or are addicted to [controlled substances](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/21/802) (which does not include alcohol). The Controlled Substances act to which the firearms law refers defined "addict" as

> any individual who habitually uses any narcotic drug so as to endanger
> the public morals, health, safety, or welfare, or who is so far
> addicted to the use of narcotic drugs as to have lost the power of
> self-control with reference to his addiction.

Ethanol is not a controlled substance, under US law.

Comment: Fascinating... Alcoholics are not precluded from buying firearms?

Comment: Nor are people who drink beer, as opposed to people who use heroin. Actually, a better way to put it is that you can't sell to a known drug user, but you can sell to a known beer-drinker.

Comment: Wait... An addict is "any individual ... who is so far addicted to the use of ..."

Comment: @DJohnM: The section isn't trying to define the *general* concept of "addict" or "addiction".  It's defining a *specific* meaning for "addict" applicable only to its use in this section.  So this *specific* sense of "addict" is defined in terms of the *general* sense of "addiction".  It's not circular.  It does leave "addiction" undefined, so it's assumed to have its common meaning.  But it's true that this doesn't answer the question of how courts usually determine, in practice, whether a person fits this definition.